# CloseEvent Qt from instance class

Tags: qt, qt4

I created a Qt form that handles the close event. In my other class (Test class), I create an instance of this form and would like to handle the close event of the form from the "Test" class.

I tried using the following code in the "Test" class, but does not seem to work .

```
connect(instanceWidget, SIGNAL(closeEvent(QCloseEvent *)), this, SLOT(handleFormCloseEvent(QCloseEvent *)));
```

Note instanceWidget is the instance of the Qt form from test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution -

Handle OnClose event in the form/UI class and inject the following code -

emit OnClose();
event->accept;

Add Signal OnClose();

In the instantiated (test class) , create a signal and slot for OnClose and provide custom funcationality.

-- Closing form , calls UI's close event handler, which emits onclose signal and gets handled by test class. after which it returns to form class and closes the form.

Answer (score 0):

The event handler methods, like `closeEvent`, are not signals, so you can't connect to them.

The event processing goes like this:

1. The event loop gets an event for given object from its queue.
2. It notifies the object by calling `object->event(...)`.
3. This method is reimplemented in `QWidget` and calls relevant specific event handler. In this case, it calls `closeEvent()`.

The signals/slots are not involved.

If you want to handle events of other objects (a `QWidget` is a `QObject`), you must [install an event filter on them](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qobject.html#installEventFilter). Your event filter will react to the event you care about, while passing onwards other events.